# How to write a JSON deserialized nested object into a database

Tags: sql, .net, json

Via REST I consume and deserialize a Json file (here I am using VB but a C# solution would be good as well)

```
Dim allDATA As List(Of GeneralInfo) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of GeneralInfo))(jstr)
```

and store it in an object

```
Public Class FullData
    Public Property userRunID As ULong
    Public Property data As List(Of String)
End Class

Public Class GeneralInfo
    Public Property id As ULong
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property data As List(Of FullData)
End Class
```

In debug mode I can click through the object and see all the data. Now I want to store the data in a database. For that I created two tables with an extra GeneralInfoId col on FullData to provide the relationship. With this code I want to write the data

```
Private Shared Sub AddData(ByRef myGDI As GeneralInfo)
...
        Using command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO GeneralInfo VALUES(@id, @name)", con)
            command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("id", myGDI.id))
            command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("name", myGDI.name))
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using

        Using command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO FullData VALUES(@GeneralInfoID, @userRunID, @data)", con)
            command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("GeneralInfoID", myGDI.id))
            command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("userRunID", myGDI.))
            command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("data", myGDI.))
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
...
End Sub
```

As you can see I do not know how to get to access the `FullData` Object's (`myGDI.???`) data. Anyone who can help me here?

EDIT:
I get survey data for all participants of a company in the json file. The `generalinfo` object has data about the company (ID, Name (of the company)) the `data` property contains a list of data of the participants like theire individual id (`userRunID`) and their questionaire `data` like Name, and result for each question (Simon;Garfunkel;1;2;3;5;5;4;4;...).
I want to write these data into a database. It would be (first off) ok to save the data in Fulldata.data as a string in the database.

Comment: This is another problem I want to handle afterwards since the data is just semicolon seperated bunch of data.

Comment: `myGDI` which is of type `GeneralInfo` does not *have* a property for `userRunID`, instead it has a list of `FullData` objects, *each* of which have that property. You need to explain more what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: I added a explanation.

Comment: Storing objects to tables is the job of an ORM like Entity Framework

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/367303/store-nested-object-from-net-to-a-sql-server/367304?noredirect=1#comment801932_367304

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a foreach on myGDI.data:

```
   Private Shared Sub AddData(ByRef myGDI As GeneralInfo)
    ...
            Using command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO GeneralInfo VALUES(@id, @name)", con)
                command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("id", myGDI.id))
                command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("name", myGDI.name))
                command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using

' Foearch here
            Foreach myData as FullData in myGdi.data
            Using command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO FullData VALUES(@GeneralInfoID, @userRunID, @data)", con)
                command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("GeneralInfoID", myGDI.id))

' Use myData here
                command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("userRunID", myData.userRunId))
                command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("data", myData.data))
                command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
    Next
    ...
    End Sub
```